# upload file to SharePoint Online via REST API issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, ajax

I have a highly customized Edit form for a list. To make life easier for users, and to manage the size of the list better, instead of attaching files directly to the list, we set up a documents library and then embedded a view of the library on the form. Documents being uploaded would go to a folder whose name matched the ID value of the list item. When we built the form in SP 2010, everything was working just fine.

Well, for a host of reasons, post-migration, this doesn't work. I'm trying to re-engineer the solution now by putting a custom upload on the form. I'm trying to upload a file via REST, but I keep getting

> {"error":{"code":-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The
>   expression\"web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/a/b/c/Requests
>   Documents')/files/add(url=filename.docx,overwrite=true)\" is not
>   valid."}}}

I know the URL is valid because when I put the URL (minus the /add...) directly into my browser, it returns results. The complete code block I'm using is

```
    var url= String.format(
    "/sites/a/b/c/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/a/b/c/Requests%20Documents/"+localStorage.folder+"')/files/add(url={1}, overwrite=true)",_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, fileName);

    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: arrayBuffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
        }
    });
```

So what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit*: On second thought, first thing to try might be wrapping the URL with single quotes: `url='{1}'`.

*Original answer:*

Try removing the space from inside the `add` function. From my experience, the comma-space sequence within functions usually causes problems in REST calls.

i.e.:

`add(url={1}, overwrite=true)`

change this to...

`add(url={1},overwrite=true)`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I did both your suggestions, to be on the safe side. But now it's working.

Comment: @ScottDavis Hi, I have same problem but I had both your suggestions already correct... my url: https://crm317842.sharepoint.com/sites/crmattachments/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/crmattachments/Shared%20Documents')/Files/add(url='test1.txt',overwrite=True)     I have same response as OP

Comment: @ScottDavis just found it... it was uppercase T in the overwrite value :( oh my .. really?